# Processing HTML document with C#

Tags: c#, html

I have a few hundred static HTML files that need to be processed.

They contain links like this

```
 <a href="http://www.mysite.com/">Link</a>
```

I need to add ?ref=self to any url that begins with `http://www.mysite.com` and becomes

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/?ref=self">Link</a>
```

however, I do not know whether it's going to be `http://www.mysite.com` or `http://www.mysite.com/` also it could be linked to a sub directory.

What's the most efficient way to do this? in C#

Comment: I asked myself the same question and gave your question a upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the most efficient way to do this? in C#

1. Look for the string `http://www.mysite.com`.
2. If it doesn't exist, go to 7.
3. Look for the next `"`.
4. If it doesn't exist, error.
5. Insert `?ref=self` before the `"`.
6. Go to 1.
7. Return.

This can be accomplished with the following regular expression substitution:

```
s#http://www.mysite.com[^"]*#&?ref=self#g
```

A nicer (more expressive) way would be to use an HTML parser and XPath.

Comment: Bug: The `href` attribute could be in single quotes ☺

Comment: @Timwi, That's not a bug.  The OP clearly stated what the expected input is (which didn't include `'`), and that efficiency was a factor (so they say...).

Comment: I don’t see where he stated that. The OP clearly stated that the expected input is **HTML**. He neither stated that it is a special subset of HTML, nor did he state that his examples are exhaustive. If I hadn’t commented, he might not have realised that any of his HTML files could contain href attributes with single quotes and that your algorithm would silently skip them.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML can be tricky as HTML often contains poorly formed tags and attributes. I suggest looking into an existing HTML parsing library to do your heavy lifting, or, using XSLT to transform valid (x)HTML to your desired output.

This question [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) has some good links to HTML parsing libraries for C#.

Comment: A html parsing library is like taking a cannon to a duck hunt in this case.

Comment: @jgauffin, I don't see how.  It's definitely an appropriate solution.

Comment: Because the URI's are quite easy to find and replace in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Page.Request.UrlReferrer to detect where the request came from.